# Calculating Monthly Orders (Integers) in Given Month From Annual Number (Integer) with Monthly Seasonality

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I want to distribute an annual number of orders across 12 months based on certain percentages while ensuring that each month only has whole orders (no fractions). When a fraction of an order accumulates to a whole, I want the next month to recognize it.. and I want this for multiple years!

|  | Year 1 | Year 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 31-Dec-22 | 31-Dec-23 |  | 31-Jan-22 | 28-Feb-22 | 31-Mar-22 | 30-Apr-22 | 31-May-22 | 30-Jun-22 | 31-Jul-22 | 31-Aug-22 | 30-Sep-22 | 31-Oct-22 | 30-Nov-22 | 31-Dec-22 |
| Seasonality |  |  |  | 2.4% | 4.9% | 9.8% | 14.6% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 4.9% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 4.9% |
| Orders | 150 | 220 |  | 4 | 7 | 15 | 22 | 14 | 15 | 14 | 8 | 14 | 15 | 15 | 7 |

The table above is an example! (Note: Seasonality =/= 100% exactly due to rounding - assume it adds up to 100%)

The annual number of orders varies year-to-year, as does the seasonality for each year. What I'm trying to avoid is a fraction of an order being recognised in a month. Anytime seasonality is >0% it needs to recognise an order has happened.

For example, say I have 150 orders in 2022. At the moment 2.4% of that will be recognised in Jan-22 (rounded *up* to the nearest whole number). However, I do not want to recognise another order in a month until there is another whole order.

Any ideas on the formula I would need to do this with formulas (rather than manual!)? :D

I tried:

```
=ROUND($A2*SUM($B$2:B$2),0)
```

In the first month, and...

```
=ROUND($A2*SUM($B$2:C$2),0) - ROUND($A2*SUM($B$2:B$2),0)
```

In the 2nd months and up to the 12th month

However, I really need to find a single formula to drag to the right for all months, as I have multiple years.

Comment: Your total **Seasonality** does not add up to **100%**. It sums to `100.3%`. How do you expect to handle that?

Comment: Sorry it's rounding - copied the table from excel! assume it adds up to 100%

Comment: How is it layed out for multiple years?  More columns with different percentages for each month depending on the year?  or More rows with the same percentages for each month regardless of the year?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Similar to the table above - years to the left, months to the right! Can't work it out!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Here are the years and the orders for each year:

| 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- |
| 31-Dec-22 | 31-Dec-23 |
| 150 | 200 |

The year is Row 1, Date is Row 2, Orders are Row 3.

The seasonality profile for each month in year of these years are:

| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Jan-22 | 28-Feb-22 | 31-Mar-22 | 30-Apr-22 | 31-May-22 | 30-Jun-22 | 31-Jul-22 | 31-Aug-22 | 30-Sep-22 | 31-Oct-22 | 30-Nov-22 | 31-Dec-22 |
| 2.4% | 4.9% | 9.8% | 14.6% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 4.9% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 9.8% | 4.9% |

1 is in Row 1 (indicating the year)
Date is Row 2
Seasonality is Row 3

Starting Jan-22 in Column D, the formula in D4 is:

```
=CEILING($A3*SUM($D$3:D$3),1)
```

Where A3 is the number of orders for 2022, D3 corresponds to the first seasonality number.

In E4, the formula is:

```
=CEILING((INDEX($A$3:$B$3,,E$1))*SUM($D$3:E$3),1) - CEILING((INDEX($A$3:$B$3,,E$1))*SUM($D$3:D$3),1)-(SUMPRODUCT( -- (E$1 > $D$1:E$1), $D$3:E$3))
```

and Voila! Now, we can enter seasonality shares for each month of the year, but always know this will correspond to a whole number of orders no matter what we put in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't supply information as to how you want the results for subsequent years. And also whether or not the percentages will be the same for each month regardless of the year.

For 2022, given the data laid out like this:

[image]

```
E4: =FLOOR(E$3*B4,1)
F4: =FLOOR(SUM($E$3:F$3)*$B4,1)-SUM($E4:E4)
```

*Select `F4` and Fill right to `P4`*

[image]

If the month percentages remain the same, and if you can put the years in subsequent rows (eg 2022 in `B4`; 2023 in `C4`) then you can merely select `E4:P4` and fill down.

If something else you will need to provide more detail.

Comment: Thank you Ron! So for the subsequent years, they would go in Col. C (2023) then D (2024) etc.. The seasonality is different for each of the subsequent years and would continue in sequence in Row 3 as you have above.

However, E4 should be rounded up to 4, rather than down to 3. This ensures that in low volume years, you have the first order when seasonality is >0%.

Comment: @Josh That is contrary to what you wrote *"When a fraction of an order accumulates to a whole, I want the next month to recognize it."* But all you need to do is change the formula in `E4`, possibly using `CEILING` instead of `FLOOR`.  And the formula for `E4` that you show in your question does not round up (*round away from zero*). It merely rounds, so, depending on the result, would not necessarily result in `1`. Please clarify.

Comment: Poor wording on my part! What I mean by "round up" is that if the seasonality is 2.4% - and this triggers 0.3 of an order, then a *whole* order should be counted (i.e. 1 additional order)

Comment: Your solution is really great for 1 year - but if I try it in subsequent months (to the right of Dec-22 in the table above), it doesn't quite work. Any ideas? Massively appreciate your help, so thank you!

Comment: @Josh What if you have more than three years?

Comment: Then I'd insert more columns to the right of the existing table where there are annual figures, and create more columns for the monthly data.

Comment: @Josh Are these two different tables then?  Or will they be in the same rows as you show in your sample?

Comment: They are in the same rows as shown in the sample :)

Comment: @Josh And will the monthly percentages be the same or different for each year.

Comment: The seasonality will be different each year